# Recurrence relation solution $a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I want to find the analytic form of the recurrence relation $$a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}},\,a_{1}=2,\,a_{2}=1 $$ but when looking at the results they seem chaotic. Is it possible that it simply doesn't have any analytic form?

Comment: Here's a possible starting point: suppose the sequence has a limit $a_{n}\rightarrow a$. Then, rearranging terms, $a_{n}(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})=a_{n-1}$. Since $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\rightarrow0$, we get $a=0$ by taking limits of both sides. Therefore, unless the limit is zero, the sequence diverges.

Comment: It does not seem to have any real-valued period-2 orbits or period-3 orbits, regardless of the initial conditions $a_1,a_2$.  If you assume $a_1=(1/2)(1-i)$ and $a_2=(1/2)(1+i)$ then we get a period-2 orbit.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228010/solving-the-recurrence-relation-a-n-fraca-n-12a-n-22a-n-1a-n-2) seems related.

Comment: There is a famous paper by Li and Yorke that "Period 3 implies chaos" for first-order maps, I don't know about second order but I thought it would be useful to look for periodic orbits. There _might_ be a period-5 orbit somewhere around $a_1\approx0.390259$ and $a_2\approx3.64934$.  If $$(a,b)\rightarrow (b,c) \rightarrow(c,d) \rightarrow (d,x) \rightarrow(x,f)\rightarrow(f,g)$$ we solve on wolfram $c=b/(b-a), d=c/(c-b), x=d/(d-c), a=x/(x-d), b=a/(a-x)$ to get https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+c%3Db%2F(b-a),+d%3Dc%2F(c-b),+x%3Dd%2F(d-c),+a%3Dx%2F(x-d),+b%3Da%2F(a-x)

Comment: @Michael Is that $ (a,b)\rightarrow(b,c) $ "stuff" a way to find where the 5-period orbit might be at? How do you know it's a 5-period orbit?

Comment: @MassimilianoTron : For example we can look for period-2 oribits by $$(a_1,a_2)\rightarrow(a_2,a_3)\rightarrow(a_1,a_2)$$ with $a_3=a_2/(a_2-a_1)$, $a_1=a_3$, $a_2 = a_3/(a_3-a_2)$. Solving gives a complex-valued solution $a_1=(1/2)(1-i)$, $a_2=(1/2)(1+i)$.

Comment: @Michael I found a nice 3-period orbit for $ a_{2} = -1.137158 $ and $ a_{1} = 0.394931 $. This is getting too exciting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer just gives more detail on my comments. Define  $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\cup \{\phi\}$ by: 
$$ f(a,b) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\left(b, \frac{b}{b-a}\right) &\mbox{ if $a \neq b$} \\
\phi  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
where "$\phi$" formally represents "undefined."  Clearly there are no fixed points $f(a,b)=(a,b)$. A point $(a,b)$, initiates a *period $k$ orbit* if: 
$$ (a,b) = \underbrace{f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ}_{\mbox{$k$ times}} f (a,b) $$ 
It suffices to look for periodic orbits with $a\neq b$.

#### period-2:

Search for $(a,b) = f(f(a,b))$, equivalently: 
$$ (a,b) \overset{f}{\rightarrow} (b,c) \overset{f}{\rightarrow} (a,b) $$
Then: 
$(a,b)=f(f(a,b))=f(b, b/(b-a))= (b/(b-a),\frac{b/(b-a)}{b/(b-a)-b})$.  Thus: 
\begin{align}
a &= b/(b-a)\\
b &=\frac{b/(b-a)}{b/(b-a)-b}
\end{align}
These two equations reduce to $-a^2 = (1-a)^2$. There are no real solutions to this equation. However, $a=(1/2)(1-i)$ and $a=(1/2)(1+i)$ are complex solutions. Using $a_1=(1/2)(1-i)$ and $a_2=(1/2)(1+i)$ produces a complex-valued 2-periodic orbit.

#### period 3:

Search for $(a,b) = f(f(f(a,b)))$, equivalently: 
$$ (a,b) \rightarrow (b,c) \rightarrow (c,d) \rightarrow (a,b) $$ 
Then the variables $a,b,c,d$ must satisfy: 
$$ c=\frac{b}{b-a} , d = \frac{c}{c-b}, a=d, b = \frac{d}{d-c} $$
It does not look like there are any real solutions.

#### period 4:

It does not look like there are any real solutions.

#### period 5:

Search for $(a,b) = f(f(f(f(f(a,b)))))$, equivalently: 
$$ (a,b) \rightarrow (b,c) \rightarrow (c,d) \rightarrow (d, x) \rightarrow (x,f) \rightarrow (a,b) $$ 
Then $a,b,c,d,x,f$ satisfy (where I use "$x$" instead of "$e$" to avoid the loaded meaning for $e = exp(1)$ when plugging into wolfram): 
$$ c=\frac{b}{b-a} , d = \frac{c}{c-b} , x = \frac{d}{d-c} , f = \frac{x}{x-d} , a=f, b = \frac{f}{f-x} $$

Numerically solving on wolfram finds 5 real-valued solutions (all cycles of each other), one is: 
\begin{align}
a &\approx 0.39025856959944318578 \\
b &\approx 3.6493359517257782682 \\
c &\approx 1.1197451069249619854 \\
d &\approx -0.44265858616085099250 \\
x &\approx 0.28331895791066755308
\end{align}
Before I suggested using $a_1=0.390259$ and $a_2=3.64934$. The Steven Harding simulation produced what looks like an *unstable period-5 orbit* (with deviations due to finite decimal truncation error).  Using $a_1=a$ and $a_2=b$ with the more accurate 20-digit-precision numbers above will likely produce a trajectory that stays close to the period-5 orbit for a longer time before deviating.

If we had infinite decimal precision then we could produce an orbit that forever stays period 5.  My guess, based on numerical observations of sensitivity to initial conditions, and intuition gained from the "Period 3 Implies Chaos" result of Li and Yorke, is that this is a chaotic system. [The Li and Yorke result holds for period 3, not period 5, and to maps of the type $x_{k+1} = g(x_k)$ for $x_k \in \mathbb{R}$, rather than $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^2$,  but I would expect the system here to also be chaotic.]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be chaotic I calculated and plotted the first 60 points of the solution.

[image: Solution]

If there was a solution it would have to have some periodic tendancies but it seems chaotic where these tendencies are and has unpredictable spikes well above the range of a normal Sin or Cos function.

Comment: Can you try plotting with the initial conditions $a_1=0.390259, 
a_2=3.64934$ to see what it looks like?  I expect period-5-ish behavior.

Comment: If $b_n=1/a_n$ then $b_n=1-b_{n-2}/b_{n-1}.$ ..I dk whether that could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
This is in response to your comment: initial conditions $a_1 = 0.390259$ and $a_2 = 3.64934$

Here's with improved precision (with sufficient error truncation), given the answer provided by Michael.

[image]

Comment: beat me to it :)

Comment: Nice!  This looks like an unstable period-5 orbit, it starts out with period 5 but then the sensitivity to initial conditions makes it deviate slightly, and then a lot.

Comment: Worth noting computing time increases dramatically past this point.

Comment: @Michael How did you figure the 5 period thing? Interesting!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD : I give some more details in an answer below.